# Materials to Understand Energy loss of neutral charged particles such as Neutrinos?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrinos, interactions

I was reading about the energy loss of charged particles in matter and understood that the Bethe-Bloch equation governs the energy loss of charged particles interacting with matter. However I was looking for a similar treatment for Neutrino with large EDM (Electric Dipole Moment) as they can interact electromagnetically and thus can lose energy in matter. Does anyone have pointers or resources to direct me ?

Thank you

Comment: Consider spelling out acronyms the first time you use them even if it might be a common one in the field.

Comment: Note that any charged loops that could create energy loss are higher level  so the weak coupling enters in higher orders. See here for measuring energy loss of cosmic neutrinos.https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/11/171122131359.htm

Comment: Thanks for the update, is there any energy loss model similar to charged particles as I don't see them in that reference ?